# HashiCorp vault error "vault: command not found"

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I am trying to run some vault commands using a shell script and it gives me an error called,

```
line 13: vault: command not found 
line 14: vault: command not found
```

But I have already installed vault and and stored a openssl key and certificate using KV secret store and successfully retrieved that key value pair using terminal commands.

This is the shell script that I have used,

```
#!/bin/sh
PARENT_DIR=sslcertnkeys
CERT_FILE=apache-cert.crt  
KEY_FILE=apache-key.key
export VAULT_ADDR='http://127.0.0.1:8200'
export VAULT_TOKEN=s.8AreSPokOQPF9Rs1xp82TDz2
# make parent directory if not exists
[ -e $PARENT_DIR ] || mkdir -p $PARENT_DIR
# remove files if exists
[ -e $CERT_FILE ] && rm -f $CERT_FILE
[ -e $KEY_FILE ] && rm -f $KEY_FILE
# retrieve certificate and key from vault and store in disk
vault kv get -field=certificate certs/apache > $CERT_FILE
vault kv get -field=private_key certs/apache > $KEY_FILE
# unset vault address
unset VAULT_ADDR
# unset vault login token
unset VAULT_TOKEN
# start apache server
systemctl start httpd.service
```

Can someone help me to figure out what is the problem in here?

Comment: `I have already installed vault`- how? Have you tested it? what's the output of `$ vault status`?

Comment: @KamolHasan yes. and I already retrieved that key value pair using `vault kv get certs/apache` and it worked.